# TDD: Code example and detailed explanation of "As the tests get more specific, the production code gets more generic."

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I try to understand better what the statement below means on Uncle Bob's [TDD Harms Architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html),

"As the tests get more specific, the production code gets more generic."

Below is my understanding on how to get more generic on production code:

- Using abstraction for method arguments, and return type, if possible
- is there more on this?

What about test code?

Ideally, code example will help understand it.

Comment: @EricLippert, I agree ... so I removed the tags... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say I try to test drive a calculator addition function.

**Test 1:**

```
public void Adding_0_And_0_Should_Return_0() { ... }
```

**Production 1:**

```
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
   return 0;
}
```

---

**Test 2:**

```
public void Adding_3_And_0_Should_Return_3() { ... }
```

**Production 2:**

```
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
   return a;
}
```

---

**Test 3:**

```
public void Adding_6_And_4_Should_Return_10() { ... }
```

**Production 3:**

```
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

You can see the tests gradually becoming more specific (taken as a whole - by applying more constraints with each case), and as a consequence, with each iteration, the implementation ends up more generic, because a single implementation needs to handle an increasing number of specific test cases.

So initially your production code can only handle a single case where the result of addition is 1.  Then with the second iteration you can handle a more generic case, where your first number can be anything you want, as long as you're adding it to 0.  With the final case, you become completely generic, by being able to add any two numbers, not just the specific ones from the earlier tests.

Comment: What an amazing concept! Writing a function that can add any two numbers!

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm actually planning on releasing an enterprise edition along these lines: https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition

Comment: @Eternal21, if you do, make sure you include a licence! FizzBuzz Enterprise Edition doesn't have one, so we couldn't use it. We had to employ 10 contractors for a year, sealed in an internet-free room, to write us our own version! Such a huge cost could have been avoided if they'd only provided a licence of some sort. :(

Comment: @Eternal21: Can you explain why you used `return a + b;` only after the third test and not after the first?

Comment: @Giorgio Because one of the tenets of TDD is to do the simplest thing possible to get the test to pass.  Returning a constant happened to be the smallest step to take there.  Obviously this is a contrived example, but it's a good practice to follow, as it prevents you from making assumptions about how the final solution should look, and allows to arrive at it in small steps, flushing out all required tests in the process.

Comment: @Giorgio In case you find it hard to decide what the *smallest step* is you can consult the [Transformation Priority Premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_Priority_Premise)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: And if you want to practice *taking* those small steps, Keith Braithwaite has created an exercise he calls [TDD As If You Meant It](http://cumulative-hypotheses.org/2011/08/30/tdd-as-if-you-meant-it/). It consists of a set of rules (based on [Uncle Bob Martin's Three Rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd), but much stricter) that you must strictly follow and that are designed to steer you towards applying TDD more rigorously.

Comment: @Eternal21: I would go even further. It's not "do the simplest thing possible to get the test to pass", it's "do the simplest thing possible to get the error message to change (in the direction of a passing test)". Likewise, I like to describe the "Red" step as "do the simplest thing that could possibly fail". Note: this requires a test framework with good error messages.

Comment: @JörgWMittag *"TDD As If You Meant It."* thanks for mentionnig it, Doing this in my [gdcr](http://gdcr.coderetreat.org/) sessions

Comment: @Eternal21 I actually know this, but I could not correlate them . Thanks for your post.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Upvote for the TPP link.

Comment: @JörgWMittag upvoted for the link.

Comment: @Priority Premise: After writing the third test, the smallest step for me would have been to add one or two `if` statements, each returning the corresponding value. My point is that `a + b` covers infinitely many cases whereas you only need to cover three tests. Or, in other words, if a function is defined on an infinite number of points, you cannot get it right by randomly choosing example inputs and outputs... unless you know in advance which function you are implementing. But then you do not need to **discover** it through TDD.

Comment: @Eternal21 Think it again, Why are these testing code considered more specific: Test 1: 1+0. Test 2: 3+0 Test 3: 6+4? They seems to the same level. Can you please provide another example for test code? Thanks

Comment: @Pingpong I modified the tests to perhaps make it more explicit?  I guess you could also change it to: Test1: Adding_Two_Integers_Should_Return_An_Integer();  Test2: Adding_An_Integer_To_0_Should_Return_That_Integer(); Test3: Adding_4_And_6_Should_Return_10();?

Comment: The problem for me is that TDD seems clear in these "toy" examples (though flawed. Why did you jump so quickly to using `+`, if you didn't already know this was the end goal?), and never for real-world examples. Please note you simply *cannot* generalize/derive `+` simply from writing a few examples and writing "the simplest code that would work", not even with Uncle Bob's "transformation" rules. I do not trust these toy examples, and have never seen a real algorithm -- i.e. one which is unknown from the start -- derived like this.

Comment: @AndresF.  To each his own.  I've been developing software using TDD methodology for almost a decade now in a professional setting, and wouldn't even dream of doing it any other way.  Just the other day I completed a Pan-Tompkins ECG QRS detector implementation that passed with flying colors on the first try against the sample database.  Does TDD work for everyone?  Definitely not. Certainly if you lack a strong understanding of IoC/DI, and how to apply it to your framework of choice, you'll never get past these toy examples.

Comment: @Eternal21 Must Tests 1 and 2 also be kept with Test 3, once Test 3 passes?

Comment: @Pingpong Since the function is simple enough, you intuitively know that test1 and test2 duplicate functionality of test3.  In real-world though you will not always be able to tell that easily, so I tend to err on the side of caution and don't remove earlier tests.